# Errors running exe after publishing a .NET Core 6.0 Console App

Tags: c#, console, .net-6.0, publish

I have a .NET Core 6.0 console app that I need to deploy. It is written in C# with Visual Studio 2022 and uses an `app.config` file.

I created a publish profile in VS (see screenshot) and deployed it locally to test before deploying to my server (list of created files attached). I ran the app using `.\executablename.exe` and it did run, but caused an error. It is not reading the config file to pull the values needed to run the app. What am I missing here?

Note: the app runs properly from a command line if I run it from the folder the project is in. However, I want a self-contained deployment so I don't need to install .NET Core 6.0 on the server.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What config file?

Comment: app.config.  It gets published as <filename>.dll.config

Comment: What error did it give you?

Comment: Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Model.Program' threw an exception.
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Model.Program..cctor() in C:\Program.cs:line 25
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Model.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Program.cs:line 34.

The code at line 25 is: 
private static string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Thing"].ToString();  and the code at line 34 is svc = new(cs);
  
Again, this code works if I run from the bin folder.

Comment: @JoanWojcicki - I had gotten myself confused, and the answer I posted about renaming the file was completely wrong, my apologies. It has to be *.dll.config, not *.exe.config.
Best of luck with solving this. When you do, please post an answer as to what the underlying problem was, I'm really interested.